# ユーザーがどのボタンが押してデバイスのスリープを解除したかを判断したい

Tags: android

Androidがスリープの状態でRFIDカードを読みたいです。
このプロジェクトで使っているカードリーダをUSBキーボードとして認識しています。

Lock Screenを使用不可にすると、デバイスがスリープしている時にも直接に入力できますが、
最初の文字が、デバイスのスリープ解除で使われるため、消えてしまいます。
例えば6桁の番号を入力すると5桁しか残らない状況です。

ですので、デバイスを目覚めさせたボタンがどれなのかを判断したいです。
ご教示お願い致します。